# get last date in month error

Tags: php, date

I have the following code which gets the date parsed, the subtracts 1 month. This works perfectly.

```
$date = '22-05-2016';
print(date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime($date.' -1 months')));
// outputs 2016-04-22 23:59:59
```

There are times where I need to force the date to month end. For this I use `Y-m-t` instead of `Y-m-d` Which works perfectly.

```
$date = '22-05-2016';
print(date("Y-m-t 23:59:59", strtotime($date.' -1 months')));
// outputs 2016-04-30 23:59:59
```

---

The problem comes when the date that is parsed is actually the last day of that month. It then flips to end of the next month.

```
$date = '31-05-2016';
print(date("Y-m-t 23:59:59", strtotime($date.' -1 months')));
```

Actual Output **2016-05-31 23:59:59** (hasn't removed 1 month)

Desired Output **2016-04-30 23:59:59**

EDIT: **Fiddle example http://ideone.com/0fqlor**

Comment: "month math" is never reliable because months are different-sized: 28,29,30,31. if you're on March 1st, subtracting one month should be what? Feb 1st? minus 29 days because it happens to be a leap year and feb comes before march? minus 31 days because march has 31 days? what if you're on march 31st, there's no Feb 31st - that'd correspond to march 2nd/3rd. strtotime has NO idea what your intentions are, so it does the best you can. you'll have to provide the logic when the result is ambiguous.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? I can't reproduce your problem with PHP 7.0.3. `$date = '31-05-2016';`
`print(date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime($date.' -1 months')));` outputs  _2016-05-01 23:59:59_

Comment: Do you mean you want to determine the last day of the month when you say 'end of month' ?

Comment: Does your first example with `Y-m-d` output  `2016-04-30 23:59:59` or  `2016-04-22 23:59:59`?

Comment: @GaijinJim ive added a fiddle example. Running php. Desired output is `2016-04-30 23:59:59` as per the other examples

Comment: @Scott typo, sorry. it outputs `2016-04-22 23:59:59`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 $date = '31-05-2016';
 print(date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime($date.'  last day of last month')));
```

and dig into `strtotime` possibilities ;)

Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Last Note: `-1 month` only gets 30 days back in time. Therefore it will not work allways. Some kind of PHP stuff, i think ;)

Comment: I got a weird result with `$date = '31-01-2016'`. It outputs `2015-12-30 23:59:59` and not `31`. I am not sure why, is this reproducible for anyone else?

Comment: U can take `-t`  to get sure, but i will take a look at this.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I didn't know about `last day of last month`. Quite literally `String To Time`

Comment: Then mark it as right answer :) And have fun with strtotime ;)

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` is your friend. The last day of any "given" month can be retrieved using the verbal String `last day of May 2015` - so, for easy input (guess you have a date-picker not a month-picker), convert the selected date to its month expression first:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$to = '31-05-2016';
$month = date("M Y", strtotime($to));
$strtotime_expression = "last day of " . $month;
echo $strtotime_expression.": <br />";
print(date("Y-m-t 23:59:59", strtotime($strtotime_expression)));
```

http://ideone.com/YvjVeP